# 504 Gateway Time-out nginx, Rails 4 (Unicorn+Nginx)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx

I was editing some of my code on my app and then decided to restart droplet from console with command `sudo shutdown -r now` .

After that I checked my droplets IP and there was 
**504 Gateway Time-out 
nginx**

My nginx error log shows:

```
2015/04/19 16:36:08 [error] 2996#0: *13 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 212.93.105.37, server: _, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/", host: "www.technorent.lv"
```

Tried to **restart / reload** then **shutdown and start** again but without success.

I definitively didn't change ANY Nginx config setup. Just my own Rails code.

Any tips.? 
Thanks